# C# MySQL Exception on Open()

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, mysql-connector

When I call this in my code:

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
    string myConnectionString;
    myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=test;pwd=mysecretpassword;database=test;";

    try
    {
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

It crashed with:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in results: charset

on this line:

```
conn.Open();
```

I didn't find anything by Google and this code is from [official MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)

PS: I'm using MySQL Connector 6.9.8 v4.5

Comment: try ip instead of localhost

Comment: Are you sure that this is all you get from the exception message? (the message seems truncated) Do you have an InnerException with a different message? (ex.InnerException.Message)

Comment: You haven't specified a port in your connection string. EDIT: for mysql the standard port should be 3306

Comment: Show all of your code, I'm pretty sure that this kind of exception can't happen on conn.Open()

Comment: I tried both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1". Port added and still same error. [here](http://i.imgur.com/BbOJGsZ.png) is link to whole exception.

Comment: Given the exception I think that something is really wrong in your install of MySql. The internal LoadCharacterSets call executes a SHOW COLLATION command and then tries to read a column called "charset". The exception seems to indicate that this column doesn't exist in the records returned by SHOW COLLATION and this is clearly not possible unless there is some kind of corruption or a big mismatch between the Connector version and the database that you are trying to read. What is the database version?

Comment: [SHOW COLLATION](http://i.imgur.com/B7J50Nf.png) and [SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"](http://i.imgur.com/QxKMdLy.png) (both by HeidiSQL)

Comment: Uhm some case difference between Windows and Linux? Could you try with a newer version of the connector?

Comment: [MySQL Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) >> .NET / Mono >> Connector 6.9.8 >> open zip file >> v4.5 - But in my DB is version 5.6.28 so there could be problem and I don't konow how to fix it